# how to stop processing jobs sagemaker?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-sagemaker

I have a problem

Recently I used sagemaker to process my jobs, with that, there were some processing jobs in the history with "Complete" status, how do I stop these jobs?

I used the command `aws sagemaker stop-processing-job --processing-job-name` 
and it didn't work the way I expected, the following message appeared when I ran it

> The request was rejected because the processing job is in status Completed.

I need to stop job processing because it is probably costing me

Answer (score 0):

You can't stop an (inactive) processing job because its already `Completed`.

To free up resources for avoiding any associated cost, try deleting the processing job with:

```
aws sagemaker delete-processing-job --processing-job-name my-processing-job
```

Note: It will delete any resources created by this job like S3 bucket/object(s).

Comment: `delete-processing-job` does not exist (`aws-cli/2.11.27`)

Answer (score 0):

aws sagemaker delete-processing-job --processing-job-name my-processing-jo
This command is not existed…

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35116465)